# How to match tilt between two bezier curves?

Tags: python

I have the following code which creates two Bezier curves which share a control point:

[image: Two curves created programmatically]

```
import bpy

def CreateBezier(cp1, cp2):
    
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_curve_add(enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.context.object.data.resolution_u = 10
    bpy.context.object.data.bevel_resolution = 0
    bpy.context.object.data.bevel_depth = 0.06
    points = bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points
    SetBezierSplinePoint(points[0], cp1)
    SetBezierSplinePoint(points[1], cp2)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

def SetBezierSplinePoint(point, cp):
    point.co = cp["co"]
    point.handle_left = cp["handle_left"]
    point.handle_right = cp["handle_right"]
    point.tilt = cp["tilt"]

cp1 = {"co" : (0,0,0), "handle_left" : (-.5,0,0), "handle_right" :  (.5,0,0),  "tilt" : 0}
cp2 = {"co" : (1,1,.5),"handle_left" : (1,.5,0),   "handle_right" :  (1,1.5,0),"tilt" : 0}
cp3 = {"co" : (2,.5,0.5),"handle_left" : (2,2.1,.4),"handle_right" :  (2,1.9,.6),"tilt" : 0}

CreateBezier(cp1, cp2)
CreateBezier(cp2, cp3)
```

The problem is where both bezier curves meet - the "tilt" is different between them:

[image: Curve join points]

Is it possible to programmatically match the tilt of the first curve when creating the second?

Comment: Not exactly sure why or how to calculate it, but setting the second control point's turn=-25.6° on the second curve fixes it: 
    CreateBezier(cp1, cp2)
cp2['tilt']=-0.446879
CreateBezier(cp2, cp3)

Comment: It may or may not help you in your use-case, but setting:     bpy.context.object.data.twist_mode = 'Z_UP'
will fix (or mask) the problem.

Comment: @RonJensen - many thanks, that solution is good enough for me. Would you like to answer it officially so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: I'm going to do some more research today to see if I can come up with a better/more complete answer. I'll create an answer later (unless @batFinger beats me to it!)

Comment: out of curiosity, why 2 curves rather than 1 curve with 3 control points?

Comment: Oh, the problem is in the way Bezier curves calculate normals along their length.  CP1-CP2 gives a different normal as you approach CP2 than CP2-CP3 does as you leave CP2, thus the mismatch in the bevel.

Comment: Unfortunately, [the fine manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/active_spline.html#bezier) is pretty useless about how to alter the tilt to compensate

Comment: @MartyFouts [the shape](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/shape.html) panel is where my suggested fix is. I remember a long lecture on this in college, but I can't remember if it was math modeling or stats... And I don't think twist was brought up.

Comment: 3rd item on that page says about Twist Method "This gives the curve a twist which can affect the curve normals. " so we're talking about the same thing, but sure if Z-up works he should go with it.  I was more or less trying to expand on your point anyway.

Comment: @RonJensen aha! [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/how-does-blender-calculate-path-normals) has an answer that is  a better way to support your point than me stumbling around the man pages.

Comment: @MartyFouts I'm using multiple separate curves rather than a single curve with multiple control points as I'm creating a tree generator, which would have multiple branches merging into other branches. As far as I'm aware this can't be achieved with single bezier curves (I could be wrong!)

Comment: You're right.  You can't have multiple segments originate from the same CP in Blender's Bezier implementation (or in any?)  I think most people "fake" their solution to the normals problem by using circular bevels and hoping that the resulting overlaps are acceptable.

Comment: Circular bevels would be a good option to hide the issue. I'm creating very low-poly abstract trees - hence the need for simple bevels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @MartyFouts, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/how-does-blender-calculate-path-normals) discusses the three different ways Blender calculates the normal (up direction) on a spline curve. The default way is "minimize" which requires recursive calculation along the spline curve. I don't know a simple way to find the normal direction from Python, but if you do find it, you can enter it as the "Tilt" value for the next spline. I estimated a value of -26° or -0.446879 radians for the OP question.

Another "Twist Method" is Z-Up. With this method the normal always (tries) to point in the positive Z direction. This method can be set in Python with:

```
bpy.context.object.data.twist_mode = 'Z_UP'
```

This will solve the alignment problem at the expense of losing the curve's twist functionality.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!